# XOML file in Workflow in designer

Tags: designer-workflow

How to paste that XOML file in the workflow in production in detail.I have followed the steps you given and related to that other sites.But still i did not succeeded. Please specify in detail

Answer (score 1):

You can use c# WorkflowCompiler class library,

```
WorkflowCompiler compiler = new WorkflowCompiler();
WorkflowCompilerParameters param = new WorkflowCompilerParameters();
compiler.Compile(param, new string[] { "MainWorkflow.xoml" });
```

For more details on above check this link -
[How to: Compile Workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms734733%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)